# Eclipse: search text in documentation pane

Tags: eclipse

Is there a way to search for text in the documentation pane of Eclipse?

E.g. see the attached screenshot showing some Android SDK documentation:

[image]

and see this screenshot showing the Search menu:

[image]

I can't see how you can do a search. And Cmd F doesn't seem to do anything either.

Comment: Try Ctrl+F, this works in most situations.

Comment: No. Ctrl+F does the same as Cmd F - nothing. I'm using Eclipse Indigo Service Release 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically a web browser pane. Sadly it is quite limited in functionality, you can't search within the view (and of course not within the documentation database instead of the currently shown document).

So the work around is to open the document in a complete, external browser. In this case it is easy to find the document (http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html) but sometimes it might be annoying to find the URL as this limited web browser view doesn't even tell it to you or gives you a possibility to get it.

If it was about site search and not searching withing the page and if the site doesn't offer a site search (this one does) then of course you can use Google with a `site:developer.android.com` parameter; similar for other search engines.

Comment: Thanks. What I feared.